# Combine XML documents with XSLT with grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to combine two XML documents, one is a list of movies and the other is a list of directors. they look like this.
directors

```
<directors>
  <director>
    <name>director 1</name>
    <born> 5/12/1992 </born>
    <nationality>Italian</nationality>
    <biography>some info on director</biography>
  </director>
  <director>
    <name>director 2 </name>
    <born>21/2/1980</born>
    <nationality>french</nationality>
    <biography>a bit about me</biography>
  </director>
```

movies

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <title> movie1</title>
    <director> director 1 </director>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
    <genre> Action</genre>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <title> movie2</title>
    <director> director 1 </director>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
    <genre> romance</genre>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <title> movie3</title>
    <director> director 2 </director>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
    <genre> Action</genre>
  </movie>
```

and i want to make the output

```
<director>
<name>director 1</name>
<born> 5/12/1992 </born>
<nationality>Italian</nationality>
<biography>some info on director</biography>
<movies genre="action">
  <movie>
    <title> movie1</title>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
 </movie>
 <movie>
    <title> movie2</title>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
 </movie>
 <movies genre="romance">
  <movie>
    <title> movie1</title>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
 </movie>
 <movie>
    <title> movie2</title>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
 </movie>
```

add movies that each director made, grouped by genre.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple, let's assume you have an XML **directors.xml**:

```
<directors>
<director>
    <name>director 1</name>
    <born> 5/12/1992 </born>
    <nationality>Italian</nationality>
    <biography>some info on director</biography>
</director>
<director>
    <name>director 2</name>
    <born>21/2/1980</born>
    <nationality>french</nationality>
    <biography>a bit about me</biography>
</director>
</directors>
```

and an XML **movies.xml**:

```
<movies>
<movie>
    <title>movie1</title>
    <director> director 1 </director>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
    <genre> Action</genre>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>movie2</title>
    <director>director 1</director>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
    <genre> romance</genre>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title> movie3</title>
    <director> director 2</director>
    <date> 1/2/2010 </date>
    <genre> Action</genre>
</movie>
</movies>
```

If you transform **directors.xml** with the following XSL Stylesheet, assuming **movies.xml** is in the same directory as the Stylesheet, you get your desired Output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="movies-by-genre" match="movie" use="genre"/>

<xsl:template match="directors">
    <directors>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="director"/>
    </directors>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="director">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="normalize-space(name)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:for-each
            select="document('movies.xml')//movie
            [count(. | key('movies-by-genre',genre)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:if test="key('movies-by-genre',genre)[normalize-space(director)=$name]">
                <movies genre="{genre}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('movies-by-genre',genre)">
                        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(director)=$name">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </movies>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <movie>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title | date"/>
    </movie>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also move the filename/path of movies.xml to a parameter and control that from your transformation arguments if you need to be more flexible.

Comment: @user3631019 sorry, I misread that I updated my answer. It now includes grouping by genre. This a often mentioned technic here called muenchian grouping, you can read up on it [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Comment: looks like I've missed that, I updated my answer, it should work now.